# Changing Edges to match angles

Tags: python, math, rotation

I'm scripting in python and I'm very new to this, and don't have a lot of experience with vector math, I can get dot product, length, and angle of two vectors, and I've managed to get the angle of difference between the two points (an edge), but I'm not sure about the math/process of actually modifying the second set of points to match the angle of the first.  What I'm trying to do is rotate the second set of points to match the first set, regardless of its current location. For example:

```
#python
import math
def dot (v1, v2):
    return (v1[0]*v2[0] + v1[1]*v2[1])
def length (v):
    return math.sqrt(dot(v,v))
def normalize (v):
    r = [0.0] * 2
    v_len = length (v)
    if v_len > 0.0:
            v_invLen = 1.0 / v_len
            r[0] = v[0] * v_invLen
            r[1] = v[1] * v_invLen                
    return r
def direction (v1, v2):
    return (v2[0]-v1[0], v2[1]-v1[1])
def angle(dotProduct):
    return math.degrees(math.acos(dotProduct))

p1,p2 = (0,0),(0,1) <--- first edge
p3,p4 = (0,0),(2,2) <--- second edge
dir = direction(p1,p2)
dir2 = direction(p3,p4)
dir_n = normalize(dir)
dir2_n = normalize(dir2)
dotProduct = dot(dir_n, dir2_n)
ang1 = math.degrees(math.acos(dotProduct))
print ang1
```

This gives me a 45 degree angle, what I'm trying to do is now rotate the second edge p2 to match the angle of p1 regardless of its location in world space so p1 might be (1,1),(-2,-2) and p2 might be (-1,1),(-3,3) with a 90 degree rotation required

Answer (score 0):

Define a new function called rotate:

```
def rotate(v,ang):
    result =[v[0]*math.cos(ang)-v[1]*math.sin(ang),v[0]*math.sin(ang)+v[1]*math.cos(ang)]
    return result

# So to rotate a given vector,lets take your example
p1,p2 = (1,1),(-2,-2)
p3,p4 = (-1,1),(-3,3)

p1,p2 = (1,1),(-2,-2)
p3,p4 = (-1,1),(-3,3)

dir = direction(p1,p2)
dir2 = direction(p3,p4)

dir_n = normalize(dir)
print ("Direction1")
print (dir_n)
dir2_n = normalize(dir2)
print ("Direction2")
print (dir2_n)
dotProduct = dot(dir_n, dir2_n)
ang1 = math.degrees(math.acos(dotProduct))

#Rotate dir2_n in direction of dir_n
new_vec = rotate(dir2_n,math.radians(ang1))
print ("rotated_vector")
print (new_vec)

Output:
Direction1
[-0.7071067811865476, -0.7071067811865476]
Direction2
[-0.7071067811865475, 0.7071067811865475]
rotated_vector
[-0.7071067811865475, -0.7071067811865475]
```

Rotated vector should be the same as dir_1. Let me know if this solves your problem

Comment: There appears to be a syntax error in result, a missing comma before v perhaps? And I think v needs to be v1

Comment: There was a minus sign missing, corrected it. try the new program

Comment: It appears to work.. but the follow up question, what can I do with the rotated vector?  The second edge (-1,1),(-3,3)  should rotate 90 degrees to match the first edge (1,1),(-2,-2) and its new values should be (-1,3),(-3,1)